# Rails - has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I’ve setup a has_many :through association between a User and Organisation model, using a Membership model as the join.

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    . . .
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :organisations, :through => memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :organisation
end
```

When a User creates an organisation, I want a membership to automatically be created linking the user to that organisation.

Where is the best place to attack this?

Options I’ve been investigating:

1. Use an after_create callback on the organisation
2. Move this process into a separate Ruby class.
3. In the organisations Controller, create action.
4. ?

How would you recommend I go about it?

Is there somewhere in the Rails Guides where it outlines best practices for this kind of thing?

Rails 4.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :organizations #-> url.com/organizations/new

#app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def new
      @organization = current_user.organizations.new
   end

   def create
      @organization = current_user.organizations.new organization_params
      @organization.save
   end

   private

   def organization_params
      params.require(:organization).permit(:x, :y, :z) #-> membership automatically created
   end
end
```

The above will automatically create the associated membership; assuming you're using `Devise` & have access to the [`current_user`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) method.

--

The best practice is the most succinct; there is no way you're "meant" to do it.

One of the biggest fallacies I see in Rails is people trying to find the most acceptable way to do something (as if there's a rulebook). The best thing you can do is *get it working* then refactor the code.

As you progress through your app, you'll find that certain patterns can be changed, some removed and many combined. The more ["DRY"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you make your code, the better it is (as a rule).

Answer (score 0):

My idea is way 3. Normaly, when set up many - many association in models, we should do creating temp table record auto through controller. 

For example in controller you can write:

```
@organisation = current_user.organisations.build organisation_params
if @organisation.save
  ....
```

So that if @organisation is save then after that memberships record auto generate.
You can see this tutorial to see that:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/what-is-a-has_many-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to do something like:

```
org = Organisation.new
org.otherstuff = "populate other stuff"
org.users = [user_who_created]
org.save
```

After that the two should be related...?  If you wanted to encapsulate this behavior you could do something like have a class method on Organization like `create_org_for_user(name, user)` and then do this logic in there, or you could do it in the controller action that handles the creation.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the best place to attack this?

I would like to say you should write this in `OrganisationsController's` `create` action to make a **`DRY`** on update action as well(use strong parameter) .Because form attribute that you are getting is from outer worlds and it is best to use `permit method` on `required params` using Strong Parametre concept.

```
def create
   @organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)
   ...
end

def organisation_params
    # here you could write all the params which you want to permit from outer worlds
end
```

Nore more info about [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any additional logic other than creating an organization and membership, I would just do #3. However, if you are planning on adding more logic for creating a new organization in the future, I would create a new [service](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) (#2).